# MQTT Mosquitto in bridge mode fails to deliver messages between Raspberry and Cloud

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, broker, bridge, mosquitto

I'm trying to connect two Mqtt Broker (Mosquitto). I installed one on a server in a cloud and another one on a local Raspberry Pi. Raspeberry Pi Mosquitto should establish connection to a cloud instance. This is my configuration on Raspberry (/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/bridge.conf):

```
connection crowdomat-cloud
address <myserver-hostname>
clientid crowdomat
start_type automatic
cleansession false
notifications true

#
# Send all messages from local /sensor topic to remote /sensor topic
#
topic # both 0 sensor/ sensor/
```

I can connect to both broker directy and send and receive messages. I also see that connection is established in the log file, but no messages are delivered between the brokers.

```
1411577927: mosquitto version 1.3.4 (build date 2014-08-22 06:10:51+0000) starting
1411577927: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1411577927: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1411577927: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1411577927: Warning: Address family not supported by protocol
1411577927: Bridge crowdomat doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic sensor/#
1411577927: Connecting bridge crowdomat-server (my-server:1883)
1411577927: Bridge crowdomat sending CONNECT
1411577927: Received CONNACK on connection crowdomat.
1411577927: Bridge crowdomat sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 466, Topic: sensor/#, QoS: 0)
1411577927: Received PUBACK from crowdomat (Mid: 465)
1411577927: Received SUBACK from crowdomat
1411577986: Sending PINGREQ to crowdomat
1411577986: Received PINGRESP from crowdomat
1411578046: Sending PINGREQ to crowdomat
1411578046: Received PINGRESP from crowdomat
1411578069: Received PUBLISH from crowdomat (d0, q0, r0, m0, '/sensor/data', ... (14 bytes))
1411578106: Sending PINGREQ to crowdomat
1411578106: Received PINGRESP from crowdomat
1411578166: Sending PINGREQ to crowdomat
1411578166: Received PINGRESP from crowdomat
1411578193: mosquitto version 1.3.4 terminating
1411578193: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
```

Any ideas?

Another mystery is, that I can see the log output only after I shotdown the mosquitto process on Raspberry Pi.

In addition the messages created by Mqtt Lens:

[image]
[image]

Comment: In your log you don't have any messages being sent from a client to the Pi (so nothing would be sent through to the remote bridge), could you rerun it including a client publish and post the updated log?

Comment: updated the log. It says that it it sending and receiving, but I can't receive any messages by mqtt lens. I'm listening to /sensor/+ onboth brokers.

Answer (score 1):

I missed this in your question before.

Your bridge is subscribing to `sensor/#` but you are publishing to `/sensor/data`. These topics don't match each other. There is a zero length hierarchy string before the first slash of `/sensor/data`, so that topic is three elements deep: `''`, `'sensor'`, `'data'`. `''` doesn't match the `'sensor'` part of your subscription, so no messages are sent.

Long story short, remove the leading slash from `/sensor/data` and it should work fine.

Comment: Hi Ralight, I tried your proposal, but it didn't help. Same behaviour as before. I added the second image, showing the result.

Answer (score 1):

Something that i figured out by bridging different devices to the Google CLoud Virtual Machine is that you need to set up a protocol version parameter in your devices(local) configuration files.

So, add the bridge_protocol_version version to your mosquitto.conf file on your RPi like this for the bridge connection connecting to the cloud (This one worked for me):

```
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
```

You can also force your configuration file on mosquttio on start like this:

```
mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/mosquitto.conf

with mosquitto.conf being the valid configuration file.
```

If you have any questions write, i have done a lot with mosquitto and mqtt.